# Array of two types

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I have two arrays :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Mon
    [1] => Sun
)

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2010-12-20
            [hours] => 4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2010-12-19
            [hours] => 2.0
        )

)
```

How to combine both as:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2010-12-20
            [hours] => 4
     [day] => Mon
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2010-12-19
            [hours] => 2.0
     [day] => Sun
        )

)
```

Thanks -
Haan

Comment: merging the arrays will not get the result your looking for - they are in different orders.  I'm going to give an answer assuming that the first array puts Sun before Mon, but if you can't rely on that this is really more of a Date issue than an array issue

Answer (score 2):

```
// copy array 2 into the result array.
$combined = $arr2;

// add a new key 'day' with value from first array.
for($i=0;$i<count($combined);$i++) {
        $combined[$i]['day'] = $arr1[$i];
}
```

[**See it**](http://www.ideone.com/tCrHt)

Comment: @ codaddict: thanks a lot. works fine. thank u all for ur valuable sugg.

Answer (score 1):

updated.

```
$secondArray[0]['day'] = $firstArray[0]; 
$secondArray[1]['day'] = $firstArray[1];
```

if you are sure thay they are both the same size:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($firstArray); $i++)
{
    $secondArray[$i]['day'] = $firstArray[$i]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to try:
$secondArray[i]['day'] = $firstArray[i];

Answer (score 0):

```
$dayOfWeek = array('Mon', 'Sun');
$dateWithHours = array( array('date'=>'12-20-2010', 'hours'=>4.0), array('date'=>'12-19-2010', 'hours'=>2.0) );

foreach(&$dateWithHours as $k=$v)
{
     $v['day'] = $dayOfWeek[$k];
}
```

Remember that ampersand.  Without it, $v is a copy that won't alter the original.  With it, it is a reference that you can change.